# Loading image from SQLite c# Windows App

Tags: c#, image, sqlite, uwp

I get the error: "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in App2.exe but was not handled in user code, Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range".

This is when trying to load an image into my app. I have the code below to load the image from my database. The filename variable returns: "Y:\\Pictures\\Cake.jpg" which is the image path im trying to load from. Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

```
            string FilePath = @"Y:\Pictures\";
            FileName = FilePath + ms.RecipeImage;
            StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(FileName, UriKind.Absolute));
            IRandomAccessStream filestream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage();
            bmpImage.SetSource(filestream);
            image.Source = bmpImage;
```

And to save to database:

```
public async void imageButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker open = new FileOpenPicker();
        open.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        open.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

        // Filter to include a sample subset of file types
        open.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
        open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
        open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

        // Open a stream for the selected file
        StorageFile file = await open.PickSingleFileAsync();

        // Ensure a file was selected
        if (file != null)
        {
            // Ensure the stream is disposed once the image is loaded
            using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                // Set the image source to the selected bitmap
                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = 200;
                bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 200;

                await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
                image.Source = bitmapImage;
            }

        }          
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible, that exception has a line of code associated with it or may be even a stack trace?

Comment: It's associated with the line: StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(FileName, UriKind.Absolute));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefromapplicationuriasync you can use GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync only with these URI-formats "ms-appx://"- or "ms-appdata://". You should be able to load ressources with this method from the assets folder for example.

**EDIT:** 
You cannot access all files and folders (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt188700.aspx). But in your case this should work (if the files you want to load are living inside the my pictures folder).

```
var filestream = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.OpenStreamForReadAsync("Screenshots\\Screenshot (1).png");
InMemoryRandomAccessStream ras = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
await filestream.CopyToAsync(ras.AsStreamForWrite());

BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage();
bmpImage.SetSource(ras);

image.Source = bmpImage;
```

Don't forget to check the Pictures Library checkbox in your package.appxmanifest.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but can I also ask if you would know how I could load it from just My Pictures folder?

Comment: Thank you SOOOOOOOOOOO much, i've wasted a day on this but you helped a lot :)